# Java (Silenium) - import statement done however method is not visible

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am relatively new to Java and Selenium.

I have a project (Selenium) created by other developer.

1. I created my Java class:

```
    public class ST_VladsSteps extends Inter
    {
    ...
    }
```

2. The class which method `SupplierPortalLogin()` I want to use is called

```
    package com.abc.application.def.tests;
    public class LoginTest {...}
```

3. In my class on the top I have put a statement:

`import com.resmed.application.GoScripts.tests.LoginTest;`

4. In my method,

```
     @When("^User keys in \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    
     public void userProvidesUserNameAndPassword(String UserName) throws InterruptedException {
    
     SupplierPortalLogin(UserName,TempString);  
    }
```

When I use the method `SupplierPortalLogin(UserName,TempString)` I have an error message,

`The method SupplierPortalLogin(String, String) is undefined for the type ST_VladsSteps.`

5. I can see in the project that other Java classes use the same
   `import com.resmed.application.GoScripts.tests.LoginTest;` statement and use this method within their methods.

Please, help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my method `@When("^User keys in "([^"])" and "([^"])"$")`

Your cucumber step required two arguments but you are passing single argument to the method `userProvidesUserNameAndPassword`

**Current code**:

```
    public void userProvidesUserNameAndPassword(String UserName) throws InterruptedException {
    SupplierPortalLogin(UserName,TempString); 
  }
```

**Updated code**:

```
  public void userProvidesUserNameAndPassword(String UserName, String TempString) throws InterruptedException {
    SupplierPortalLogin(UserName,TempString); 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.  Really appreciate.

Comment: Glad. It helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This method requires 2 arguments,

change your method from

```
public void userProvidesUserNameAndPassword(String UserName)
```

to

```
public void userProvidesUserNameAndPassword(String UserName, String
Password)
```